# Prevent editing files outside solution

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging

Visual Studio allows me to open an external file in order to debug it, which is great for debuging solution's dependencies. Unfortunately, Visual Studio also allows me to edit this external file. It is extremely misleading because this way I edit a file that does not belong to my current project.

How to open external files in "read-only" fashion, so I **can** put break points in them and **cannot** change their content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, VS doesn't have this feature unless we know that which files were called before we really debug them, so we could edit the files' property like read-only before we debug the app.

I also help  you submit a feature request to the product team:

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/31557271-prevent-editing-files-outside-solution

You could also vote and add your comment there.

Comment: Thank you. I have registered my support for this feature request and I hope it gets implemented.